# How can I add a "SET ECHO ON" to a SQL query piped into sqlcl as I can do with "SET SQLFORMAT CSV"?

Tags: oracle, shell, pipe, sqlplus, sqlcl

For embedding in Unix shell scripts I want to execute a set of SQL commands and exit sqlcl straight afterwards.

For this I use successfully the pipe-from-stdin method:

```
echo "SELECT COLA FROM MYTABLE;" | sql -L <connectionstr>
```

which return the query result to stdout. Great!

Now I want to "decorate" the query with some directives for `sqlcl`. E.g. I want to change the output format:

```
echo "SET SQLFORMAT CSV;\n SELECT COLA FROM MYTABLE;" | sql -L <connectionstr>
```

Works like a beauty! Sometimes I want to add echoing of the SQL command:

```
echo "SET ECHO ON;\n SELECT COLA FROM MYTABLE;" | sql -L <connectionstr>
```

Surprisingly **this does not work**! The `"SET ECHO ON;"` directive is ignored. However if I do

```
echo "SET ECHO ON;\n SELECT COLA FROM MYTABLE;" >combined_query.sql
echo @combined_query.sql | sql -L <connectionstr>
```

*then* it works. Is there a way to make `"SET ECHO ON;"` work in a direct pipe without the detour via a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is 'no'. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-F7A23B0A-540E-4CB6-B1D4-CD241DA8B1BB):

> ECHO does not affect the display of commands you enter interactively or redirect to SQL*Plus from the operating system.

That's the SQL*Plus documentation; the [SQLcl documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/23.2/sqcug/set-system_variable-value.html#GUID-5B365E3E-B4A8-45CA-A13B-CD41F5FCC156) doesn't go into much detail but in general it behaves the same as SQL*Plus.

Comment: I see! Thank you. This makes total sense.